# udevadm and simulating state change

Tags: udev

I am referring to the following link:

[An introduction to Udev: The Linux subsystem for managing device events](https://opensource.com/article/18/11/udev)

In this link, an example is shown demonstrating how udevadm can be instructed to invoke a script based on a state change induced by `ACTION="add"`, implying a device is plugged into the system.

I would like to know whether there is a way to simulate this state change, without actually having to unplug and plug the device again into the system, so that I should be able to execute a script by means of udevadm by just reloading udevadm.

Appreciate your thoughts

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create any event using `udevadm trigger <device>`. Default action is `change`, other actions can be specified using `-c <action>`. See [udevadm manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/udevadm.8.html) for more information.